# Scala/Play: access current url in a model

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a simple Play application in which I need to check url being called and use different database accordingly. I know that it's easy to access current url in the controller, but for this to work I need to access it in the model.

Passing the url from controller to each call of a model method would be too big of an inconvenience. Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Play Framework 2.2.1 / Scala 2.10.3

**UPDATE:** This is my basic example

Controller (`Application.scala`):

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._

import models.Data

object Application extends Controller {

    def index = Action {
        //Call to model method - model should somehow get the URL without it being passed as a param        
        val smth: String = Data.getSmth()
        Ok(smth);
    }

}
```

Model (`Data.scala`):

```
package models

object Data {

    def getSmth: Option[String] = DB.withSession {
        val db = //this is where I need the url to decide which database to use
        sql"""SELECT #$db.smth FROM smthTable""".as[String].firstOption
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think it possible to access current url in model. Because the model does nothing to do with http. May be you can define an implicit request parameter in you model constructor. But I don't think this is a good idead.

Comment: @jilen How would I define that parameter in my model constructor? I still need to pass it or access it somehow. Surely, a situation like this shouldn't be uncommon?

Comment: ```case class Foo(val bar: Int, val baz: String)
case object Foo {
  def apply(bar: Int)(implicit request: play.api.mvc.Request[_]) = new Foo(bar, request.path)
}``` something likes this, this is really not a good idea.

Comment: @jilen I don't think this is what I'm looking for. I must say I'm quite disappointed that such an obvious and common issue doesn't have a solution on Play.

Comment: It has, you either pass it explicitly or you pass it implicitly.

Comment: @johanandren Would you care to elaborate it with an example? If this means passing url as a param from any controller to any model method, you might see why I don't think it's a very good solution.

Comment: If your model classes wants some data, in this case data that depends on each request, there are two choices, one is to try to introduce a 'context' and store stuff in a ThreadLocal, this would require Play to sync the data between threads when you use async and would also make it next to impossible to unit test your code as you would have to fake that context - this is the bad (tm) solution, Play does something like this in the Java version of the APIs.

Comment: The right way to do it is to express the data that classes and methods wants and provide it, to make this a bit easier if it is something you need in many function calls you can use implicits which is a parameter list like any that you can call and provide that data explicitly in tests or where you do not want the implicit. This is the good (tm) solution.

Comment: Of course you shouldn't let your model know about the Request class as that would tightly couple it to the controllers, instead you could introduce your own class, that you could create with an implicit conversion from Request in your controllers and that you easily could fake in your model.

Comment: @johanandren Sorry, but if I understood what you just wrote here, I probably wouldn't have needed to raise this question in the first place. Can you give me an example?

Comment: ah, sorry, working with this stuff all day made me think it was obvious, ill post an answer with an example instead.

Answer (score 1):

So, this is by design in the Play Scala API - there is no magic context, if you want data you will have to pass it along to whatever piece of your code that needs it.

You will have to take the url as a parameter of some kind, you could do it like this:

```
case class MyModel(someData: String, requestUrl: String)

object MyModel {
  def apply(someData: String, request: Request) = 
    new MyModel(someData, request.url)
}
```

This would clearly express the dependency, but in your particular app you might call this from every request and want to avoid having to repeat providing that parameter, in that case you can use Scala implicits which makes the compiler look for a matching implicit instance that is of the same type in the current scope (you can read more about this here: http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/114).

```
object MyModel {
  def apply(someData: String)(implicit request: Request) = 
    new MyModel(someData, request.url)
}
```

which could then be called from a controller action like this

```
def myAction = Action { implicit request => 
  val model = MyModel("blablabla")
  ...
}
```

Of course it may be a bad idea to tightly couple your model to the play Request API and you should probably introduce your own class to represent this 'context', you could then implicitly convert from `Request` to `YourContext` in you controllers and have the model implicitly use `YourContext` instead.

If all this sounds like gibberish to you, you should probably start with actually learning Scala before trying to build a web app in Scala. There are lots of good books nowadays ('[Scala for the impatient](http://horstmann.com/scala/)' for example) as well as a multitude of good online resources ([the neophytes guide to scala](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/11/21/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-1-extractors.html) is a good one).

Good luck!

Comment: I know enough Scala to scrape together a CRUD app, but this is still confusing. I've updated my question with my own example, obviously with a couple gaps that are the whole point of my question.

Comment: Ok, reading your updated question my answer is still the same, you cannot pass data to a function in scala in any other way than passing it as a parameter.

Comment: It's hard to believe that Play can't do something that any shitty PHP MVC framework can do. Well if you say it's not possible, I guess it's not possible.

Comment: Play doesn't do it because it breaks the MVC paradigm. There's a reason those PHP frameworks are shitty, as you say.